# Is there a way to simplify this SQL function? I feel like its redundant

Tags: sql

just not sure if I'm doing this the best possible way. Is there a way I can shorten it? It works with what im looking for, but im trying to learn and not sure if this statement is redundant?

`select first_name, last_name, SUM(amount) from staff s, payment p where s.staff_id = p.staff_id and p.staff_id = "2" ;`

Comment: Looks pretty simplified to me. What about this feels redundant? If anything this is over simplified

Answer (score 2):

I recommend writing this as:

```
select s.first_name, s.last_name, sum(p.amount)
from staff s join
     payment p 
     on s.staff_id = p.staff_id 
where p.staff_id = 2
group by s.first_name, s.last_name;
```

I don't see any "redundancy".  But I do see room for improvement:

- Your query needs a `GROUP BY`.
- Always use proper, explicit, **standard** readable `JOIN` syntax.
- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- Do not escape numbers.  Presumably, `staff_id` is a number, so just compare to `2` not `"2"`.
- Qualify all column references so it is clear what table they come from.
- The `GROUP BY` should probably include `staff_id`, in case two staff members have the same name.